# GCP Workflows: append to array

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

Using GCP / Google Workflows I'd like to take an array and apply a transformation to each one calling http endpoints. To do this, I'm looking for a way to apply the transformation and then re-assemble the results into another array. One way to do this is [experimental.executions.map](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/experimental.executions/map), but it's an experimental feature that's subject to change, so I'm a little hesitant to use that. Another way to do this is to start with an empty array and append to that array as the transformation is applied. Is there a way to do this? Concatenating a string seems to work, but there doesn't seem to be a built-in away to append to an array. I tried something like this, which does execute successfully, but doesn't yield the expected result:

```
main:
  steps:
    - assignVariables:
        assign:
            - sourceArray: ["one", "two", "three"]
            - hashedArray: []
            - hashedString: ""
            - i: 0
    - checkCondition:
        switch:
            - condition: ${i < len(sourceArray)}
              next: iterate
        next: returnResult
    - iterate:
        assign:
            - hashedArray[i]: ${"#" + sourceArray[i]}
            - hashedString: ${hashedString + "#" + sourceArray[i] + " "}
            - i: ${i + 1}
        next: checkCondition
    - returnResult:
        return:
            - hashedString: ${hashedString}
            - hashedArray: ${hashedArray}
```

Actual result:

```
[
  {
    "hashedString": "#one #two #three "
  },
  {
    "hashedArray": []
  }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "hashedString": "#one #two #three "
  },
  {
    "hashedArray": ["#one", "#two", "#three"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending items to lists is now supported using [list.concat](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/list/concat):

```
assign:
    - listVar: ${list.concat(listVar, "new item")}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are wondering how to solve this problem using the experimental  [experimental.executions.map](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/experimental.executions/map) feature, you can do it like this:

First create a callable workflow that will transform the array. I gave this workflow a name of `hash-item`. This name is important, as we'll refer to it as `workflow_id` later:

```
main:
    params: [item]
    steps:
    - transform:
        assign:
            - hashed: ${"#" + item}
    - returnResult:
        return: ${hashed}
```

Then create your main workflow, which calls `hash-item` using  `experimental.executions.map`:

```
main:
  steps:
    - assignVariables:
        assign:
            - sourceArray: ["one", "two", "three"]
    - transform:
        call: experimental.executions.map
        args:
            workflow_id: hash-item
            arguments: ${sourceArray}
        result: result
    - returnResult:
        return: ${result}
```

The service account used to execute the main workflow will need the `workflows.executions.create` permission (usually via `roles/workflows.invoker` role). To assign this, you can do this with the Cloud SDK CLI:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project-id> --member="serviceAccount:<service-account-email>" --role="roles/workflows.invoker"
```

Executing the main workflow will output the desired result:

```
[
  "#one",
  "#two",
  "#three"
]
```

Note: [experimental.executions.map](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/experimental.executions/map) is experimental, so subject to change.